# what's the definition of partial correlation for a population?

Tags: partial-correlation

is partial correlation only defined for a given sample? the definition based on residuals as on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_correlation) seem to imply that's the case. is there a population definition for partial correlation?

Answer (score 0):

This is comparable to correlation in sample / population for "normal" correlation.
Only in partial correlation, you talk about the effect of X on Y partialled out for Z.